# Mongo $near - How to add a second query?

Tags: mongodb, express

I have a route that does a $near search on my mongo database. It returns documents that have a geo tag within 100 miles. This request searches each document for "bandLocation". I have a second field, that is indexed, called bandTour - It holds several other geo locations in the same format. I want the request to also include these locations but have been unsuccessful - How do I add the second query?

Here is my route - If "bandLocation" is the only request, it works... How would I add "bandTour"?

```
   router.get('/allbands/:lng/:lat',   (req, res) => {
    quoteGenerator.find(
        {
        "bandLocation.geometry":
            { $near :
                {
                $geometry: { 
                    type: "Point",  
                    coordinates: [parseFloat(req.params.lng), parseFloat(req.params.lat)] 
                },
                $maxDistance: 160934,
            }
            },
            "bandTour.geometry":
            { $near :
                {
                $geometry: { 
                    type: "Point",  
                    coordinates: [parseFloat(req.params.lng), parseFloat(req.params.lat)] 
                },
                $maxDistance: 160934,
            }
            }
        })
.then(
                function(bands){
                    res.send(bands)
                }
            )
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB only supports a single geo-expressions such as `$near` in a query.  While aggregation does support geo queries, it is only supported as the first stage of the pipeline, so aggregation is not a solution in this case.

You would need to implement this as 2 queries, then combine the results.  Since your sample query is requiring both locations to match, you could use a find with `$near` on `bandLocation`, projecting just the `_id` field.  Then use the returned `_id` values to build a second query that tests for `_id:{$in:[_array of ids_]}` along with the `$near` on `bandTour`